# Angular 5 send data from angular to express

Tags: angular, express, mean

I'd send my data from angular to express using subscribe, but it didn't work.

This is my ProfileComponent.ts from angular :

```
  updateProfileCompany(e){
    var getUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    getUser = JSON.parse(getUser)
    var id_student = getUser["id"];
    var nim        = getUser["nim"];
    var nama       = getUser["nama"];
    var email      = getUser["email"];
    var id_company = this.company;
    const user = {
      id         : id_student,
      nama       : nama,
      email      : email,
      nim        : nim
    }
    console.log(user);
    this.authService.updateProfileCompany(user)
    .subscribe((res:Response) => this.user = user);
  }
```

And this is my authService.ts :

```
    updateProfileCompany(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    var users = localStorage.getItem(this.user);
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    return this.http.put('http://192.168.100.10:3000/users/update', user, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

And on my express give undefined value from user.

```
router.put('/update', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next)=>{
    user = req.user;
    var id_student = user.id;
    var id_company = req.body.company; 
    var result = [];
    console.log(user.id_student);
});
```

When I try to console.log all of user data from angular, it returns undefined.

Comment: where you got `undefined` is that route getting called?

Answer (score 1):

Your user object that you are sending in the ajax request is in the req.body object

```
router.put('/update', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}),(req, res, next)=>{
    user = req.body; // here
    var id_student = user.id;
    // var id_company = req.body.company; this you should add to the object that you are sending
    var result = [];
    console.log(user.id);
});
```

The user object sent has this structure

```
const user = {
  id         : id_student,
  nama       : nama,
  email      : email,
  nim        : nim
}
```

So you can not do console.log(user.id_student) because is not there.

Instead do console.log(user.id)

Comment: const user = {
      id         : id_student,
      nama       : nama,
      email      : email,
      nim        : nim,
      id_company : "ID Company"
    } But if I console.log id_company it returns undefined

Comment: console.log(user.id_company )

Comment: It returns undefined